# How to calculate how much voice channels is being multiplexed

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, data, transmission

I would like to know how I could calculate from the bitstream which has a bitrate of 2,048 Mbps into how much voice channels is being used. I know that the syn has 32 bits and sign is 16 bits.

Bitrate = sampling frequency * bits/frame

If we would model the dataframe then we would get something like this:
syn + S1 + S2 + Sn...........+ sign

Now the problem is that we want to know how much Sn(t) there is which must represent the voice channels.

But when I use the bitrate of 2,048 Mbps and subtract the syn and sign and divide that with the 8000 Hz sampling frequency and then each voice channel is 8 bit then I get a huge numer which I think is not logical.

Before I can do the other questions the first question is quite tricky ;-)

[image]

[image]

Asked:
**a. Calculate the number of voice channels that are multiplexed in a primary group.
Let's see how you do that**.

b. Draw the composition of a data frame of a primary group
Indicate clearly the duration of the frame and the number of bits per sample.

c. How many bits of the frame of the primary group are now "lost" to the
signalling and routing information? What percentage of the frame now consists of
real voice information?

d. How many voice channels are there in a supergroup? How many percent of the
frame of the supergroup now consists of real voice information?

e. What is the baud rate on the connection? Motivate your answer.

f. What is the required transmission bandwidth BW on the cable?
Please justify your answer.

Comment: It’s 2MHz not 2GHz

Comment: The answer is 32 voice channels muxed with data to a higher bit rate then ASK modulated on a 420MHz carrier

Comment: If you have to ASK ...